# Window 'load' event not firing when tab is in background

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom, events, dom-events

I have attached an event listener to the window's load event using the following code:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
   console.log('window loaded');
});
```

When I navigate to my site and then switch to another tab before it has finished loading, the load event never fires and the 'window loaded' text is not printed to the console. This problem occurs exclusively in Chrome.

Has anyone faced this issue in the past? I have searched way too long for a solution online but to no avail. I am using the latest version of Chrome and have confirmed the issue is not isolated to just my machine.

Comment: I ran into the same issue last week. The same thing happens in Safari and Firefox. This doesn't seem like appropriate behavior. I'm going to investigate this further.